# How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

There are many questions/answers available here to understand `Ramp up time` but I want to get something in detail for my test case.

**Test Case** : Expecting 1200 users per 5 minutes on the home page. So it will be like 5 users/second.

I have set following `thread properties` :

```
No. of Threads : 1200

Ramp-up Time - ? [I am not sure what to set]

Loop count - Forever

Scheduler - 300 Seconds[5 Minutes]
```

Can anyone please help me to set `ramp up time` for my test case? I am running the test on my local machine.

I want to check that how many users server can handle in 5 minutes. Our expectation is `1200 users`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per you **test case** and **duration** settings, I think, you are making confusion with the **Threads and Requests**.

**In short:** You must use Ramp-up as **`240 seconds`** for this scenario.

Let me describe you in details:

**Ramp up** is the time in which all the **users** arrive on your tested application server.

**Requests** are simulated by **samplers** but **threads** are the simulation of **users**.

***Please note-*** The total number of **requests** are related to **throughput**, Whereas the number of active threads performing the same activity is related to **concurrency**.

**From your requirements**, I assume you want to measure the throughput which is related to the **requests/second** not the **users per second**. To achieve this, you can use a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) at your **test plan level**.

**Constant Throughput timer** allows you maintain throughput of your server (`requests/sec`). Here **requests** are **samplers**. **Threads are users/clients which are requesting server using samplers.**

You can achieve this by using both **"`Thread Group`"** or **"`Ultimate Thread Group`"**.

**As far as I know, it doesn't matter which type of Thread group you are using with Constant Throughput timer**, at the end of the test in the results, you will get your desired Throughput which you mentioned in Constant Throughput Timer i.e. if you have mentioned **1200/min** in Constant Throughput Timer with **"Calculate Throughput based on"** value as **"All active threads"** and there are 3 requests (samplers) in your thread group then JMeter will manage the requests in a way that it will generate only **6.6 requests/sec** for each sampler i.e. 1200/min is divided among 3 requests, it doesn't matter whether you are using **Ultimate Thread Group** or the **Thread Group**; Throughput timer works in same way for all types of thread groups.

**Now as per your requirement: (Using Thread Group):**

```
No. of Threads : 1200

Ramp-up Time - 240 (Since you want 5 users per second, 1200/5= 240)

Loop count - Forever

Scheduler (Duration) - 780 Seconds [13 Minutes]
```

**IMPORTANT:**

> Thread Group configurations will be the same which you have already mentioned. Number of threads will be the client load which you want to put(`in you case it's 1200`), `duration : (240+300+240)`, `loop : forever`, `ramp-up : 240` yes when you ramp up i.e. in the first minute generally you get more requests as threads are starting so it is normal behavior. **To test your scenario run for exactly 5 minutes**, you should test for `13 minutes`. Exclude first 4 min and last `4 min` of the test as that is warm up time for your test as well as server and last `4 min` are warm down period.

**Now as per your requirement: (Using Ultimate Thread Group):**

```
Start Thread Count: 1200
Initial delay, sec: 0
Startup, sec: 240 (I assume you want 5 users come to your application for requesting expected samples per second)
Hold Load for: 300 sec (Since you required 5 minutes to test for 1200 users)
Shutdown Time, sec: 240
```

**You can set just like this:**

[image]

Don't get confuse the **Thread number** with the number of **requests**, each thread will create multiple requests for seconds in field **Hold Load for**.

Comment: Thanks for answer and detail explain. Can you please tell me what is incorrect in answer of @Adnan?

Comment: For this scenario, more specificly ramp-up periods and test duration. Test duration should be 13 min to mimic your requirements. Ramp up time should be 240 seconds or 4 minutes since you want 5 users per second on your application server.

Comment: I have already described it on important section in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I am changing my test case setting in ultimate thread as per your given guilde.

Comment: I followed ultimate thread group but test is not stopping after 5 minutes. I can see 1200 active users. Total in how many minutes test will get stop?

Comment: The test will get stop after 13 minutes. I've already mentioned in the important section. "To test your scenario run for exactly 5 minutes, you should test for 13 minutes. Exclude first 4 min and last 4 min of the test as that is warm up time for your test as well as server and last 4 min are warm down period."

Comment: How can I minimize that time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121451/discussion-between-mirk-and-helping-hands).

Answer (score 3):

Rampup is the speed at which users arrive on your application.
The number you put means that once it is reached all threads have been started.
The tiniest it is , the faster users arrive.
So nobody can answer that for you, you need to analyse your traffic.

Regarding the number of threads, 1200 threads might not be the good number, as 1200 users can navigate on application slowly or rapidly. 
What you need is add a Constant Throughput Timer to control how much transactions per second you'll be reaching.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Ultimate Thread Group` plugins available in Standard set.
To maintain concurrency the configuration should be like this:

```
Start Thread Count: 1200
Initial delay, sec: 0
Startup, sec: 60
Hold Load: 180
Shutdown Time, sec: 60
```

**Ultimate Thread Group**
[image: Ultimate Thread Group]

Here all the `1200 threads` will be generated and up within `60 sec` of `Startup time`(Ramp up time) .Those 1200 threads will be active for next `180 sec`, and after that, those threads will shut down within next `60 sec`.

So overall duration of the test is 300 sec as you desire. Throughout the `Hold Load` time(180sec) the requests will be looped.
This ultimate thread group will give you more control over Threads.

Now if you want to control the rate of `transactions per second` or the number of samples to execute you can use `Constant Throughput Timer`. Constant Throughput Timer will let you control the flow of requests to be sent. The default `"Thread Group"` only control the way the users or threads will be generated.It doesn't control the rate of requests to be hit your application.So for this purpose, you could use "Constant Throughput Timer" to control your requests per second. For further detail, you could go through JMeter [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

Comment: Thanks for assist. I have set everything as per given guide. Now for default thread group what should I set?

Comment: In default thread group  `ramp up time= 60` and there is no option to control the `ramp down` those 1200 threads.

Comment: ok but if I use ultimate thread group then I don't need default thread group. correct?

Comment: I have put ultimate thread but getting this error while run it - **jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.start**

Comment: What is the `jmeter` and `java` version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121426/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-adnan).

Comment: Jmeter : 3.0
Java : 1.8

Comment: Please let me do some research on this issue on the internet. As soon as I come up with some viable solution, I will get to you.

Comment: Yes please. I did research but did not get helpful answer.

Comment: what was the issue? please tell me how,  as it may help me in future.

Comment: Did you installed UTG from `Plugin manager` or just pasting `JMeterPlugins-Standard` set in the `/lib/ext` location

Comment: When I have installed plugin via plugin manager then only it worked. Before that I have used separate JAR of ultimate thread to EXT folder but that was not helpful.