# Requests and Threads understanding in JMeter logs

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am still confused with some JMeter logs displayed here. Can someone please give me some light into this?

Below is a log generated by JMeter for my tests.

```
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:02 =    0.5/s Avg:  1631 Min:  1631 Max:  1631 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 2 Finished: 0
summary +    218 in 00:00:25 =    8.6/s Avg:   816 Min:   141 Max:  1882 Err:     1 (0.46%) Active: 10 Started: 27 Finished: 17
summary =    219 in 00:00:27 =    8.1/s Avg:   820 Min:   141 Max:  1882 Err:     1 (0.46%)
summary +     81 in 00:00:15 =    5.4/s Avg:   998 Min:   201 Max:  2096 Err:     1 (1.23%) Active: 0 Started: 30 Finished: 30
summary =    300 in 00:00:42 =    7.1/s Avg:   868 Min:   141 Max:  2096 Err:     2 (0.67%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Jun 09 04:19:15 IDT 2017 (1496971155116)
```

Does this log means [ last step ] 300 requests were fired, 00.00:42 secs took for the whole tests, 7.1 threads/sec or 7.1 requests/sec fired?

How can i make sure to increase the TPS? Same tests were done in a different site and they are getting 132TPS for the same tests and on the same server. Can someone put some light into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a little of theory:

- You have [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(s) which should mimic real user actions
- You have Threads (virtual users) defined under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which mimic real users
- JMeter starts **threads** which execute **samplers** as fast as they can and generate certain amount of **requests per second**. This "request per second" value depends on 2 factors:

  - number of virtual users
  - your application response time

JMeter [Summarizer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-2-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode) doesn't tell the full story, I would recommend generating the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the .jtl results file, it will provide more comprehensive load test result data which is much easier to analyze looking into tables and charts, it can be done as simple as:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/testresult.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard/output/folder
```

Looking into current results, you achieved maximum throughput of 7.1 **requests** second with average response time of 868 milliseconds.

So in order to have more "requests per second" you need to increase the number of "virtual users". If you increase the number of virtual users and "requests per second" is not increasing - it means that you identified so called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and your application is not capable of handling more.

Answer (score 2):

In here, total number of requests is 300. Throughput is 7 requests per second. These 300 requests generated by your given number of threads in Thread group configuration. You can also see the number of active threads in the log results. These threads become active depend on your ramp-up time.

Ramp-up time is the speed at which users or threads arrive on your application.

Check this for an example: [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038)

You can give enough duration in your script and also check the loop count forever, so that all of the threads will be hitting those requests in your application server until the test finishes.

When all the threads become active on the server, then they will hit those requests in server.

To increase the TPS, you must have to increase the number of threads because those threads will hit your desired requests in server.

It also depends on the response time of your requests.

Suppose,

1. If you have 500 virtual users and application response time is 1 second - you will have 500 RPS
2. If you have 500 virtual users and application response time is 2 seconds - you will have 250 RPS
3. If you have 500 virtual users and application response time is 500 ms - you will have 1000 RPS.