# Run with 10 users by using google.com, but in summary report. samples are displaying more than 10k

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image: Adding Stepping Thread Group]

[image: Adding 10 users in thread group]

[image: Summary Report]

My Question is: I am run with the 10 users for google homepage, but while i'm seeing in the Summary report the samples are above 1L.

Can anyone please help us on this..?

Comment: 10 users are generating those samples/requests within the test duration time. Sample generation is related to Throughput.

Comment: As per Jmeter's blog, This plugin is deprecated and should not be used. Use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) instead."

Comment: I tried with Concurrency also, still the samples are showing 183316.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are making confusion with the Threads and Requests.

In JMeter, Threads are the virtual users here. Those users/threads will hit your target application server. In this case, 10 users are hitting on the google.com homepage within the test duration. These 10 users will invoke to the server according to your given ramp-up time. See this for an example: [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038)

On the other hand, Samplers are requests. These requests are generated by those 10 threads. In this case, your 10k samples are generated by your defined 10 threads/users within your test duration.

Comment: I'm little confused on thread group and Concurrency Thread Group. While same users run on Normal thread group the samples are 10 samples but when i'm trying on Concurrency Thread group the samples are above 1L.        I don't know where am missing..!

Comment: @Sai Karthik In concurrency thread group there is no way to control the loop count where it's possible for Normal Thread Group. If loop count forever is checked and then run the test again you will find the sample count ~1L

Comment: Whatever the thread group you are using, the threads will make those requests in the server within your test duration. Now, if there is loop count available and checked forever, then those requests will be generated without any control until the test has finished. If loop count value is given as 2, then each of those 10 users will hit the google.com homepage twice. That means total 20 samples will be generated by those 10 users. Thanks.