# How to add 10 threads every 1 minute?

Tags: jmeter

I want to add 10 threads every 1 minute in my load testing.I put 300 seconds in my duration equivalent to 5 minutes. So the total threads are 50 after the test. Heres the config in the thread group.  I am using JMeter GUI.

```
Threads: 10
Ramp up: 1
Duration: 300 seconds
```

Comment: can you be specific abt language you are using and share snippet of code

Comment: I am using jmeter gui

Answer (score 3):

Ramp up is the time in which all the users arrive on your tested application server.

In [Thread Group documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Thread Group also provides a scheduler. Click the checkbox at the bottom of the Thread Group panel to enable/disable extra fields in which you can enter the duration of test, the startup delay, the start and end times of the run. You can configure Duration (seconds) and Startup Delay (seconds) to control the duration of each thread group and the after how much seconds it starts. When the test is started, JMeter will wait Startup Delay (seconds) before starting the Threads of the Thread Group and run for the configured Duration (seconds) time. Note those 2 options override the Start time and End time.

Set your Thread Group like this:

```
No. of Threads: 50

Ramp-up Time - 300sec (Since you want 10 users per min, 10*60*5= 300)

Loop count - Forever

Scheduler (Duration) - 900 Seconds [Total 15 Minutes: 5 mins for users ramping up time, 5 mins for your test and 5 mins ramping down time]
```

To know the details, you can also see this thread on [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038).