# Performance testing in production environment using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, dev-to-production

Hi stack Overflow community,

i need your valuable help
 I developed a script for our web application using Jmeter and Blazemeter chrome plugin
Scenario as
login >> walkthrough some pages >>logoout
Script working successfully in our local environment. I am using summary report as a Listener and non Gui mode for performing test

Now i need to do load testing for 250 usesr on client production environment.
measurement points are
1.Response time for each request
2.Data traffic Size
3.CPU and memory utilization

i have so many questions:
1.what all points i need to consider  when I run my script on production environment
2.Do i need to add ramp up time.
3. real environment have having proxies and load balancers.(our local doesn’t have)
4.Do I need to keep all .png,  css ,gif as recorded by tool  or I can disable them.is it effect my results?
what changes i need to do to make my script compatible to such environment.

Considering i a m new to Jmeter and automation testing and no help on this tool other than blogs, stack overflow community and google.
Very much tense about its real implementation.
Thanks in advance as u help someone to grow.

[image: My script structure looks like this]

Do i need to change structure of my script also. if no Kudos to me ,if yes plz direct me, appreciate if someone provide screenshot for right type of structure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the points which should answer most of your questions:

1. You should not run script on Production environment if your product is live, you should run it on production like environment.
2. You can only simulate APIs so no css, png are required.
3. Ramp up you will have to decide as per your requirement.
4. Structure can be divided in transactions, it would be more proper.
5. You need to check your script once with the Production like environment as it is having proxies and load balancers which your local environment does not have.
6. Whatever things you need to measure, there are different plugins available for it on Jmeter.
7. Do make sure most of the things are parameterized as much as possible.
8. When running your test, monitor both database as well as application server.

For more details or reference you can go through below urls:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial

http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/performance-testing-videos.html

Comment: Thnks for Replying SRM21.  one more question,How to decide ramp up time and who will decide it for automation tester. or tester himself

Comment: That call is generally made with discussions with someone who knows the expected load and as per the domain of your application. For Example, for an e-commerce site you can normally expect 1 user is logged in per 5 seconds, but when the sale is going on, 100 users might simultaneously log in 1 second. So, as per the scenario you want to simulate you can decide ramp up time.
But this was how I used to decide ramp-up.
You can refer below answer to refer how other users are deciding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter

Comment: Thnks SRM21 for replying...its such a gr8 help