# Is there any cirteria for "ramp up " time , what should be the ramp time?

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

1. Is there any criteria for set "ramp up " time , what should be the ramp time ?
   lets for example, i need to execute script for 30 minute(duration) and 100 concurrent users(threads) so what should be ramp up time for same.
2. What should be duration for for execution jmeter script? normally we execute for 30 minutes is this correct ?or is there any criteria for same ?

Comment: Here is another detail discussion about [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038)

Comment: @jahan.. can you please explain more .. as on what basis we can find our ramp up time and duration for execution script .. i could not understand properly

Comment: It depends on your test plan like how you want your users to be alive on the server (ramp-up)and how much time you need to execute your test plan (test duration). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should receive the answers from the [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) for your application

1. According to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

   > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
   >
   > Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.
2. Your test should last long enough so all virtual users would be able to finish their scenarios. It should be definitely longer that the ramp-up time otherwise you may run into the situation when some JMeter threads have already finished their work and were shut down and some hasn't yet been started. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/) for more details. Also if you're executing a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) the duration could be several hours or even days

Comment: Can you please elaborate for ramp up calculation and duration as above is generic answer, basically i want to know the best way for find out the ramp up time and duration (in which we need to execute script).

Comment: Please help me on this