# JMeter sending less requests than expected

Tags: performance, jmeter, threadgroup

I'm using jmeter to generate a performance test, to keep things short and straight i read the initial data from a json file, i have a single thread group in which after reading the data i randomize certain values to prevent data duplication when i need it, then i'm passing the final data to the endpoint using variables, this will end up in a json body that is recieved by the endpoint and it will basically generate a new transaction in the database. Also i added a constant timer to add a 7 seconds delay between requests, with a test duration of 10 minutes and no ramp up, i calculated the requests per second like this:

1 minute has 60 seconds and i have a delay of 7 seconds per request then it's logical to say that every minute i'm sending approximately 8.5 requests per minute, this is my calculation (60/7) = 8.5 now if the test lasts for 10 minutes then i multiply (8.5*10) = 85 giving me a total of 85 transactions in 10 minutes, so i should be able to see that exact same amount of transactions created in the database after the test completes.

This is true when i'm running 10-20-40 users, after the load test run i query the db and i get the exact same number of transaction however, as i increase the users in the thread group this doesn't happen anymore, for example if i set 1000 users i should be able to generate 8500 transactions in 10 minutes, but this is not the case, the db only creates around 5.1k transactions.

What is happening, what is wrong? Why it initially works as expected and as i increase the users it doesn't? I can provide more information if needed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be 2 possible reasons for this:

1. You discovered your application [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing). When you add more users the application response time increases therefore throughput decreases. There is a term called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) which stands for the maximum performance of the system, if you go beyond this point - the system will respond slower and you will get less TPS than initially. From the application under test side you should take a look into the following areas:

   - It might be the case your application simply lacks resources (CPU, RAM, Network, etc.), make sure that it has enough headroom to operate using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
   - Your application middleware (application server, database, load balancer, etc.) are not properly set up for the high loads. Identify your application infrastructure stack and make sure to follow [performance tuning guidelines](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/) for each component
   - It is also possible that your application code needs optimization, you can detect the most time/resource consuming functions, largest objects, slowest DB queries, idle times, etc. using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)
2. JMeter is not sending requests fast enough

   - Just like for the application under test check that JMeter machine(s) have enough resources (CPU, RAM, etc.)
   - Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - Consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check once CPU and Memory utilization(RAM and java heap utilization) of jmeter load generator while running jemter for 1000 users? If it is higher or reaching to max then it may affect requests/sec. Also just to confirm requests/sec from Jmeter side, can you please add listener in Jmeter script to track Hit/sec or TPS?

Answer (score 0):

This will also be true(8.5K requests in 10 mins test duration) if your API response time is 1 second and also you have provided enough ramp-up time for those 1000 users.

So possible reason is:

- You did not provide enough ramp-up time for 1000 users.
- Your API average response time is more than 1 second while you performing tests for 1000 users.

**Possible workarounds:**

- First, try to measure the API response time for 1 user.
- Then calculate accordingly that how many users you need to reach 8500 requests in 10 mins. Use this formula:

  > TPS* max response time in second
- Give proper ramp-up time for 1000 users. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038) to understand how you should calculate ramp-up time.
- Check that your load generator is able to generate 1000 users without any memory or health (i.e CPU usage) issues. If requires, try to use distributed architecture.