# Jmeter - Calculating Ramp-up period

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to send 1100 requests per minute to my API endpoint for a period of 5 minutes, so in total, I will make 5500 requests to the endpoint.

Based on the above requirement, Here is how I have set up my Jmeter:
[image]

It seems like I have misconfigured Jmeter, because in the end I can see Jmeter has made **8401** requests to the API instead of **5500**.

What have I missed in the configuration?

Does the "Infinite" check-box need to be checked or unchecked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of requests you're expecting (which is **5500**) for this test plan is **wrong**.

As per your expectation, I think, you are making confusion between the Threads and Requests.

**Ramp up** is the time in which all the users arrive on your tested application server.

**Requests** are simulated by samplers but threads are the simulation of users.

**According to your test plan:**

```
- Total Number of Threads: 1100 vitual users
- Ramp-up time: 60 (1 min)
- Loop count: Infinite
- Test duration: 300 sec (5 min)
- No of requests/sampler in Test Plan: Unknown, assuming it 1
```

**JMeter Execution:**

JMeter will kick off those 1100 virtual users in `60 seconds` according to the ramp-up time. So, `(1100/60)~ 18` users will be active in every second for the first minute of your test. Each thread/user will execute the requests or samplers you have defined in your test plan hierarchy. As you have defined the loop count to `infinite`, each thread will execute the requests repeatedly until the test finishes. After 60 seconds, all of your 1100 users will be actively hitting those samplers/requests for the remaining `4` mins.

So the total number of requests you will be able to make through JMeter depends on your application **response time**.

If the avg response time of your requests is `1 second (assuming you have only 1 requests in your test plan)`, then you will be able to hit total `264000 (264000/240 = 1100 requests per second)` for the last 4 mins (when all of your 1100 users are active) of your tests. You can also verify this accordingly by using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listeners.

So, Please double check the avg response time of your application or the requests/samplers you are using in your test plan.

If you want to control JMeter's throughput to `1100 per minute`, you can use a [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) at your test plan level and use `target throughput value as 1100`.

Do not forget to add the count of `ramp-down time` in your test duration. Yes, when you ramp up i.e. in the first minute generally you get more requests as threads are starting. In your case, your test duration should be `7 mins (60 seconds for the ramp-up 1100 users + 300 seconds for 5500 requests + 60 seconds for the ramp down for 1100 users)`.

You can also check this thread for more : [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter).

> Please note- The total number of requests is related to throughput, Whereas the number of active threads performing the same activity is related to concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to send 1100 requests per minutes to my API endpoint for a period of 5 minutes, so in total I will make 5500 requests to the endpoint.

I don't know how you came with this `5500` number but this is not very correct.

Your setup means that:

1. JMeter will add 18 virtual users each second for 60 seconds
2. After 60 seconds pass JMeter will run 1100 users for another 4 minutes

The total number of requests JMeter will be able to make will mostly depend on **application response time**.

If you want to limit JMeter's throughput to 1100 requests per minute consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

If you don't want to limit JMeter's throughput but want 5500 executions either:

- Set "Loop Count" to 5 (but in that case you might fail to get 1100 concurrent users)
- Or use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in `Total Executions` mode so JMeter would stop after executing 5500 requests

Comment: I got 5500 by multiplying 1100 request to 5 minutes, so 1100x5=5500