# How can i do Stress/Performance Testing in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I Want to go for stress testing to start with the anticipated number of users (or just from 1 virtual user) and gradually increase the load such as for 10 threads, 20 threads, …. 100 threads until response time starts exceeding the acceptable value or errors start occurring.But For all this test run should i increases the Ramp-up Period(Seconds) or it will remain the same for all test?
Picture is given below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Ramp-up time shouldn't be the same for all of your tests. You have to set the Ramp-up period accordingly.

> Ramp up is the time in which all the users arrive on your tested application server.

You can check this thread also: [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038)

Comment: Thanks,But when i add 10 threads what should be ramp up period,when will i add 100 thread what should be the ramp up period and so on?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.**

So if you don't have a better idea - go for the ramp-up period in seconds equal to the number of users.

The point of ramp-up is increasing the load **gradually** so will be able to correlate increasing load with other [performance metrics for websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) like response time, throughput, number of server hits per second, number of errors per second, etc.

See [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for the metrics which are stored by JMeter explained